# Приведение типов в C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

У меня есть код:

```
char ASCII_symbol = 82;
String^ eee = "" + ASCII_symbol;
```

Во время дебага видно, что в ASCII_symbol хранится 82 'R', но когда происходит создание строки в нее записывается "82". Как можно по другому получить символ по его коду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В показанном коде нет приведения типов.

В данном случае код равнозначен этому:

```
"" + ASCII_symbol.ToString();
```

То есть при конкатенации автоматически вызывается метод `ToString`: в итоге значение символа преобразуется в строку `82`. Вообще, конкатенацию следует убрать, оставив вызов метода.

---

Самым простым способом преобразования будет следующий:

```
String^ eee = Convert::ToChar(ASCII_symbol).ToString();
```

Тут тип `char` неявно приводится к `int`.

---

Далее, *управляемый* тип `System::String` C++/CLI состоит из двухбайтовых символов `System::Char`. Между тем тип `char` из *неуправляемого* (нативного) C++ имеет размер один байт.

Если вам нужно корректно преобразовывать однобайтную кодировку ASCII в многобайтную кодировку UTF-16 (Unicode), то используйте методы классов `*Encoding` (их там несколько) из пространства имён `System::Text`. Например:

```
array<unsigned char>^ bytes = gcnew array<unsigned char> { ASCII_symbol };
String^ eee = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString(bytes);
```

Метод `GetString` принимает на вход массив, поэтому пришлось один ваш `char` поместить в массив.

---

Предвосхищая вопросы: "Хочу использовать ASCII в C++/CLI везде и всюду, почему не работает?" Ответ: потому что весь API платформы .NET завязан на многобайтный юникод. Тип `System::String` **не может** содержать в себе никакую другую кодировку. Он может состоять **только** из двухбайтных `System::Char`.

Соответственно, литералы должны указываться с префиксом `L`:

```
String^ s = L"Привет";
Char c = L'Ю';
```